# MySql check if foreign key constraint exists

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

If I have:

```
create table order_items
( 
  orderid int unsigned not null references orders(orderid),
  isbn char(13) not null,
  quantity tinyint unsigned,

  primary key (orderid, isbn)

);
```

How can I check if `orderid int unsigned not null references orders(orderid)` foreign key exists?

Comment: Try: [21.17 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/referential-constraints-table.html).

Comment: Accept the answer below if it covers the question topic.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = '<schema>'
AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'order_items'
AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'orderid'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to check foreign key constraints from whole database

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME ,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
    REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
```

need to check particular table means please add this where condition in the above query

```
WHERE
    REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'student' AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'student_details'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'referenceTableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA  = 'schemaName' AND TABLE_NAME = 'mainTableName' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'constraintName'
)THEN
    //Execute query whatever you need
END IF;
```